# “*altra* possibilità che soccombere o reagire” Vs. “*altre* possibilità che soccombere o reagire”

Tags: grammatical-number

> Circondati da pericoli e non avere *altra* possibilità che soccombere o reagire è il futuro che aspetta gl'italiani, uno sgradevole farwest.

*altra* è corretto lì? O, invece, è prescritto usare *altre*?

Comment: Dipende se per te *possibilità* è singolare o plurale: alla fine è il numero di opzioni rimaste che si suppone siano 0... e 0 non è nè singolare nè plurale.

Comment: Grammaticalmente, zero è plurale. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Lo puoi riferire alla mancanza di una terza alternativa (un'altra possibilità) altro che soccombere o reagire che sono le uniche due scelte possibili.

Nel caso stai esprimendo l'idea di una terza alternativa puoi usare *altra*, o se vuoi dare l'idea di più di una alternativa alle due che seguono l'espressione puoi usare *altre*. Entrambe sono corrette per conto mio e non cambiano il concetto espresso dalla frase.

Answer (score 0):

Certo, è corretto.  Si riferisce a "soccombere OPPURE reagire", quindi una sola possibilità, al singolare. Ma non credo che sia sbagliato usare "altre", riferendosi a tutt'e due le possibilità.

Comment: soccombere o reagire sono due possibilità, non si riferisce a quelle